# How do I specify what computers can connect to my public facing Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

How do I lock down my Windows 2008 R2 Server so only certain computers can connect to it? I would ideally like to use some sort of certificate rather than an IP as my IP changes. I've done this in Linux, but I don't know where to start with Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'other computers' you mean 'other Windows computers' you can use IPSec policies to determine who is allowed to talk to the machine. IPSec policies use a pre-shared key (not quite a certificate) between various stations to allow/disallow contact. Unfortunately, I haven't actually used them for this purpose, I just know it can be done.